# Errors in newly created Android project?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am struggeling with a problem compiling my first android program.

I created a new android program and want wo compile it but i get errors without even having made a change on it.

heres a screenshot:

http://www.pic-upload.de/view-13539041/Unbenannt.jpg.html

has anybody an idea what the problem is?

greetings and thx in advance

Comment: Can you post your android manifest file also?

Comment: eek, linking to a site that opens other windows, ..... just post the errors here, what you had wasn't of much use anyway

Answer (score 0):

Its something got to do either with the debug key expiring. You need to generate a new one. Follow this guide.

http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/08/android-error-error-generating-final.html

Prior to that make sure you have the latest adb and adt pair.. update all ur tools to the latest version and try again.

Comment: np.. please mark this post as the answer if the solution works for you.